# The meaning of phonon

Tags: phonons

I learnt that [phonon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonon) is quantum something of vibration. But I cannot understand what 'phonon concentration' and 'phonon scattering' mean, and how they relate to the temperature or carrier mobility. Does it have a intuitive picture?

Comment: You can consider (acoustic-)phonons as particles of sound waves. Sound waves travel through crystals, they can scatter, their propagation speed depends on temperature (volume expands), carrier mobility, ...

Comment: Related: [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/78442/what-is-a-phonon](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/78442/).